# Copy File From Teams to File Server Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, document-library

I am trying to copy a xlsx file from my Teams channel to a location on a file server.

I've seen various articles on line that suggest `Invoke-WebRequest "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/file/rest of URL here" -OutFile C:\Test\CricketQuiz.xlsx`. While this works in terms of being able to see the file at the desired file location, I can't actually open it as I get this error:

[image]

I get the same error when I tried the approach suggested in this article https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell .

```
$url = "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/file/rest of my URL here"
$output = "C:\Test\SportsQuiz.xlsx"
$start_time = Get-Date

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
```

I'm guessing this is something relatively straightforward to resolve for those with more experience.

Comment: What is file extension, of the file you are trying to download? Can you download it and open it without script?

Comment: Since all Office XML files are packed as zip archives, the first thing to check is whether the downloaded file is indeed that: `(Get-Content $output -Encoding Byte |% ToString X2) -join ' '` - you should expect the result to be `50 4B 03 04`.

Comment: You are trying to download a file and mark it as xlsx which it is not.

Comment: The file on Teams is Xlsx

Comment: @SSingh When you paste the URL into a browser, does it start downloading the file automatically, and then closes the tab, or does it show you a page from which you can then click "Download file" or similar?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the link you've got (the Teams link) is not a direct link to the file at all - it's a link to an embedded version of the file, inside the Teams client (basically like a deep link). To -actually- download the file try the following:

1. from the url you've got, parse out the "objectUrl" part of the query string. As an example, I have:

`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/file/[guid]?tenantId=[guid2]&fileType=xlsx&objectUrl=https%3A%2F%2F[tenantname].sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FHR%2FShared%2520Documents%2FEmployee%2520Sentiment%2520Analysis.xlsx&serviceName=recent`

you want (in my example): https%3A%2F%2F[tenantname].sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FHR%2FShared%2520Documents%2FEmployee%2520Sentiment%2520Analysis.xlsx

2. then you need to querystring decode this, to get (e.g.) https://[tenantname].sharepoint.com/sites/HR/Shared%20Documents/Employee%20Sentiment%20Analysis.xlsx
3. finally, you should use the [PnP-PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) module's [Get-PnPFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps) to download the file. This itself is a few steps though:

3.1 you need to connect the session, using Connect-PnPOnline, but you also need to connect to the right "SPWeb". In this case, it would be `Connect-PnPOnline https://[tenantname].sharepoint.com/sites/HR`

3.1 after that you can download the file, but you need to url decode it again, to get rid of %20 and similar, something like:

`Get-PnPFile -Url "/Shared Documents/Employee Sentiment Analysis.xlsx" -AsFile -Path "c:\temp\"`

This will give you a copy of Employee Sentiment Analysis.xlsx (in my example) inside c:\temp

Obviously this can all be automated, like the querystring decoding, the connect-pnp credentials, etc., but hopefully this gets you on the right path.

Comment: Is it possible to automate this process if the Office365 has MFA enabled? If so, how?